# Railsのgem will_paginateを利用した際に、２ページ目の場合にデザインを変更したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

rails　のgem [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)を利用した際に、２ページ目の場合にデザインを変更したいのですが、
手順が分からず、ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授頂ければと存じます。

categories__controller

```
def show
  @category = Category.where(slug: params[:slug]).first!
  services = @category.family_services
  services_num_per_page =  5
  @services = services.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: services_num_per_page)
end
```

view  categories/show.html.slim

```
  == render 'categories/partials/hoge1'
  - if 下記を２ページ目では非表示
    == render 'categories/partials/hoge2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

READMEなどを見る限り、will_paginateが提供する機能では2ページ目以降のデザインを変更するのは難しそうです。
実現できる方法としては自分でCSS/SCSSを記載してスタイルを適用するくらいだと思います。

ページネーション自体（1ページ、2ページ目関わらず全て）のスタイル変更は、以下の2つの方法がありそうです。
要件にもよると思いますが、こちらも検討してみてはいかがでしょうか。

1. 以下のページにあるデザインのCSS/SCSSをDLして使用する
   http://mislav.github.io/will_paginate/
2. 以下のGemを利用してBootstrapのデザインを使用する
   https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/will_paginate-bootstrap

Comment: やはり対応できそうにないですか、、ありがとうございました。
頂いた２つの案で工数的に対応するかしないか検討いたします。　早急に対応いただきありがとうございました